# Base of a Topology of $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: general-topology

> Prove that all infinite arithmetjc progressions of positive integers is a base of a Topology on $\mathbb{N}$.

Let $\mathcal{B} $ be the collection of all arithmetic progressions of positive integers. Now consider an $x \in \mathbb{N}$. We want to show that there exists a arithmetic progression, call it B, such that $x \in B \subseteq \mathcal{B}$, and also, if $ x\in B_1 \cap B_2$ then, $\exists B_3$ such that $ x \in B_3 \subseteq B_1 \cap B_2 $.

I have no clue on how to begin proving this, thus I am not in search of a proof but hints on how to at least get the ball rolling.

Comment: Given a set $X$ and a family $B$ of subsets of $X$ where $\bigcup B=X$ (i.e. $B$ "covers all of" $X$), $B$ will always be a subbasis for some topology on $X$. What is required of a subbasis to make it a basis?

Comment: Well, at least tell us what does a set of subsets have to fulfill to be "a base" of some topology...and then try to check this in your case!

Comment: @DonAntonio I have added this to my edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $x \in B_1 \cap B_2$, where $B_1 = \{a_1 + nb_1: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ for some $a_1,b_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ and likewise $B_2 = \{a_2 + nb_2: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Now, consider $b_3 = \operatorname{lcm}(b_1, b_2)$, (least common multiple) then it's clear that $x \in \{x + nb_3: n \in \mathbb{N}\} \subseteq B_1 \cap B_2$, as required.

Answer (score 0):

Given a set $X$ and a family $\mathcal{B} \subseteq P(X)$, $\mathcal{B}$ forms the basis for some topology on $X$ if and only if (a) for each $x \in X$, there is some $B \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B$; and (b) for each $B_1, B_2 \in \mathcal{B}$ and $x \in B_1 \cap B_2$, there exists some $C \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in C$ and $C \subseteq B_1 \cap B_2$.

(Then the exact topology for which $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis is the family of unions of elements of $\mathcal{B}$.  Or, put another way, $U \subseteq X$ is open in this topology if and only if for each $x \in U$, there exists $B \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B$ and $B \subseteq U$.)